# mysql, order by index doesn't work with selecting the whole colomns

Tags: mysql, sql

I use mysql 5.5, innoDB and have been trying to understand indexing rules of it.
I encountered a problem related to `order by` but couldn't find any clear answer by googling.

There is a simple table, like this `test_table`:

```
idx : index (int), Primary key, auto-increment

test_datetime : datetime, index(test_datatime)

some_dummy_col1 : dummy1(varchar)

some_dummy_col2 : dummy2(int)
```

I indexed `test_datetime` and tried a query like:

```
select idx, test_datetime from test_table order by test_datetime desc;
```

Running `explain` showed exactly what i intended (`type: index, Extra: using index` and so on..) but when I try to get the whole row by `select *`, `explain` shows `using filesort`. 
I tried to increase the number of the test data to 300,000 rows or so. It still produces the same result.

Could anyone explain why selecting index columns only works but selecting `*` is not working..?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use this `FROM test_table FORCE INDEX (idx)` to force mysql to use your desired index

Comment: thanks for very quick reply, catalinetu. ok, i will try now. i just wonder, why indexing is affected by the choice of selecting columns.

Comment: Give the query planner and optimizer a chance to work.  Run analyze table and show index.

Comment: This goes into detail on why this may be happening: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28592/must-an-index-cover-all-selected-columns-for-it-to-be-used-for-order-by/28640#28640?newreg=30e1ad021a014a179c7f81b349944df2

Answer (score 0):

First consider the query:

```
select t.test_datetime
from test_table t
order by test_datetime desc;
```

The index you have *covers* this query.  That means that all the columns in the index are in the query.  So, the SQL engine has an easy job to return the results:  just read the index in order and return the `test_datetime` column from the index.

When you expand the `select` list to:

```
select t.*
from test_table t
order by test_datetime desc;
```

Then the SQL engine can no longer just read the index.  Instead, it has two options.  One is to read the index in order (satisfying the `order by`).  Then for each record in the index, it needs to look up the records in the data pages to get the additional columns.

The alternative is to sort all the data.  MySQL has decided that the "sort all the data" option is the better choice for this particular query in your environment.

That is not as crazy as it sounds.  If your table does not fit into memory, then the index method could result in something called "thrashing".  This is a worst case for reading data and could be even slower than doing the sort.

Answer (score 0):

The note "Using index" in the EXPLAIN plan means using *only* the index, that is, getting the needed columns from the index alone, without having to read any rows from the table. This is called an index-only query.

But it works only if the select-list includes only columns included in the index definition. InnoDB additionally allows the primary key column(s), because all secondary indexes implicitly include the PK columns even if you didn't define the index that way.

If you use `SELECT *` then you're not able to get "Using index" (unless your table only has a few fields and the index covers them all). But that doesn't mean MySQL isn't using the index at all. It just means that it has to read the rows in addition to reading the index.